# Javascript - passing anchor into a span from .innerHTML

Tags: javascript

I have an external js file, wanting to put a link into a span on the html file.

```
   function QuizDetails() {

    document.getElementById("quiz-link").innerHTML = <a href="quiz.html">Take quiz again</a>;

 }
```

The html code

```
<p><span id="quiz-link"></span></p>
```

For some reason the js dosent run, the code below works fine but obvious I want to pass an anchor. Any ideas?

```
   function QuizDetails() {

document.getElementById("quiz-link").innerHTML = "take quiz again";
```

}

Comment: You are just missing quotes, change: 
document.getElementById("quiz-link").innerHTML = <a href="quiz.html">Take quiz again</a>; 
by document.getElementById("quiz-link").innerHTML = '<a href="quiz.html">Take quiz again</a>';

Answer (score 0):

you are missing quotes...

```js
    document.getElementById("quiz-link").innerHTML = '<a href="quiz.html">Take quiz again</a>';
```

```html
<p><span id="quiz-link"></span></p>
```